# How do I move everyone from a certain role into a channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js

The code needs to be able to see everyone in a certain role, then put all of them in a voice channel.

```
const team1role = message.guild.roles.find("name", "Team 1");
const voice = args.join(" ");
const chan1 = message.guild.channels.find("name", "Team 1");
team1role.setVoiceChannel(chan1);
```

This error shows up:

```
TypeError: team1role.setVoiceChannel is not a function
    at pass.run (F:\Discord_Bot\expbotworking\Experiance\commands\move.js:17:17)
    at Client.bot.on (F:\Discord_Bot\expbotworking\Experiance\index.js:26:11)
    at Client.emit (events.js:197:13)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (F:\Discord_Bot\expbotworking\Experiance\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (F:\Discord_Bot\expbotworking\Experiance\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (F:\Discord_Bot\expbotworking\Experiance\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (F:\Discord_Bot\expbotworking\Experiance\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (F:\Discord_Bot\expbotworking\Experiance\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:197:13)
```

Comment: Might need to see more of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `team1role` is an instance of role, not members. You'd have to get all the members from said role and set the voice channel for each of them.

Below you can find example code, give it a try and let me know how it goes.

```js
const team1role = message.guild.roles.find((role) => role.name === "Team 1");
const team1members = team1role.members;

const chan1 = message.guild.channels.find((channel) => channel.name === "Team 1")

team1members.forEach((member) => {
  member.setVoiceChannel(chan1);
});
```

Comment: It worked thanks! btw one of the servers bots that I was making this for banned everyone!

Comment: The owner's bots Token got taken from him and then the person who did that banned everyone with his bot.